# VSWR WOW measurement

Tags: terminology

I see the term WOW in spec sheets and drawings. I understand the term means a variation in a measurement (VSWR, Insertion Loss, Phase) over 360 degrees of rotation. But I have never correlated how the term WOW is connected to the meaning.

What is the origins of this term? Is it an acronym?

Comment: Not familiar with that usage.  WoW in aviation speak is short for "weight-on-wheel", which means the aircraft is down and resting on it's wheels.  It's used to prevent bad things from happening, like accidentally launching a missile while on the tarmac.

Comment: https://www.spinner-group.com/images/download/technical_documents/SPINNER_TD00021.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Given I have never been in microwave RADAR R&D only VLF and VHF and I have never heard WOW,  except when someone mutters something about a VSWR of 1.2 at the transmitter and 10 at the antenna, I have a hunch.

Also, it's not the low-frequency rumble with wow & flutter.

Worst (change) over Wavelength  = WOW for millimeter wavelength microwave devices.

**This parameter describes how much the VSWR changes over a full rotation at the "worst" frequency within the specified frequency range**.

Think of it as the **incremental impedance loss variation** measured by reflection ratio or return loss over a full wave length or 360 deg.
Even the Chinese engineer in suppliers of these products understands it.